# Trying to get firefox running on CentOS 6 minimal iso - can't open display

Tags: x11, firefox, centos

I've got minimal CentOS 6 running on an Oracle VirtualBox on a Mac. I'm trying to get Firefox up and running so I can download some web files into the VM.

I installed Firefox (`yum --enablerepo=remi install firefox`). I also installed Xserver (`yum install xorg-x11-server-Xvfb`) as I wasn't sure if it was included in the minimal OS install.

I then `export DISPLAY=10.0.5.52` and then tried to start `firefox` but it said:

> Error: can't open display: 10.0.5.52.

What do I need to do to get `firefox` to display?

Comment: Do you want Firefox to place its windows on the Mac or inside the CentOS window?

Comment: why not download files using `wget`

Comment: Xvfb is a virtual frame buffer and is not going to help you.  wget/curl is your best bet if you want to stick as close as you can to the minimal package group you installed initially.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this:

```
$ export DISPLAY=10.0.5.52:0
```

Then run Firefox again. Also be sure to run `xhost +` on the host 10.0.5.52 so that it's able to accept X applications being "sent" to it from other servers. This method is considered poor from a security stand point but is perfectly fine to use to confirm things are working properly. With that working, spend a bit more time considering your security posture in this use case and do something a bit more explicit using `xhost +someremoteserver` instead.

Also you could use `ssh` to tunnel the X application instead of using `xhost`. There's typically a bit of a performance hit but it's often tolerable and worth it in my opinion.

```
$ ssh -X someremoteserver firefox
```

*excerpt from ssh man page*

```
 -X     Enables X11 forwarding.  This can also be specified on a per-host 
        basis in a configuration file.
```

Comment: Actually using export DISPLAY=10.0.5.52:0 had no impact. Still get error: cannot open display 10.0.5.52:0 when issuing the firefox command at a command prompt. I also started xhost + on my host first, which started up an instance of X Windows (I think that's what happened, this is a little new to me).

Comment: @Jazzmine - you have to run the command `xhost +` on 10.0.5.52 as well. The permission denied is the other server disallowing the Firefox window from being sent.

Comment: Ok, I just ran xhost + on the guest (VM) terminal and it automatically responded with xhost: Unable to open display "10.0.5.52:0"

Comment: And a little bit more info: i got my ip address from the VM's ifconfig command and selected the inet ip address. Sound good?

Comment: @Jazzmine - you ran `xhost +` on the host with the actual desktop, right?